# Asserting object equality in Javascript test (chai)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, chai

I need to assert equality between two points in my JavaScript unit tests:

```
var pnt1 = {x: 2, y: 3};
```

and

```
var pnt2 = {x: 2, y: 3};
```

When I do

```
assert.equal(pnt1, pnt2);
```

It says the points are different. Can I exclude from the check the fact that the objects are different instances (so in fact they are "not equal")?

I'd like to avoid creating a list of assert, one for each field to test (in this case `.x` and `.y`)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Instead of `.equal`, use [`.deepEqual`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/#method_deepequal):

```
assert.deepEqual(pnt1, pnt2);
```

This will perform a deep comparison instead of simply checking for equality.

Comment: brilliant. so deepEqual will traverse the object till the basic types (where we don't have the concept of different instances, at least in JS).

Comment: That's the gist of it, yes, @GianlucaGhettini.

Comment: If it's not obvious, `assert.deepEqual({a: 1, b: 2}, {b: 2, a: 1})` is also true, even though OP's example object keys are in the same order.