# chai throw with property deep equal

Tags: chai

`expect.to.throw` returns a Proxy to the thrown Error, so I can use `with.property` in order to check some properties of the error.

I attach a `details` object on my custom errors but I can't test for them, since the `with.property` compares only using strict equals.

**Can I compare this property using deep equal somehow?**

Example:

```js
class DocNotFoundError extends Error {
  constructor(message, docId) {
    super(message)
    this.details = { docId }
  }
}

const getDoc = id => {
  throw new DocNotFoundError('errors.docNotFound', id)
}

const docNotFound = expect(() => getDoc('01234567890')).to.throw('DocNotFoundError')
docNotFound.with.property('details', { docId: '01234567890' }) // fails
```

The error will fail similar to

```
AssertionError: expected { Object (error, ...) } to have property 'details' of { Object (docId) }, but got { Object (docId) }
+ expected - actual
```

I assume this is due to it only checks for reference equality and not deep object equality.

Comment: Would you mind sharing minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Vulwsztyn can you use this to reproduce? I am using it within a simple mocha unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is a typo in the question: `DocNotFoundError` should not be in quotes.

I managed to get it working with `docNotFound.to.have.deep.property('details', { docId: '01234567890' })`, so yes you should perform deep comparison to check if objects have keys with same values.

[Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935705/asserting-object-equality-in-javascript-test-chai)

[Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526805/chai-test-array-equality-doesnt-work-as-expected)

Comment: Thank you that worked out very well! One comment to your answer, can you please remove the sources? I think they both are dealing only with general deep equality and not with property equality **of expected thrown errors**, right?

Comment: why should I remove the sources if they could help someone and do you no harm? they helped me solve this

Comment: Ok no problem then